# Flask RESTFUL, creating a cookie from an endpoint (restful.Resource)

Tags: python, rest, cookies, backend, endpoint

I'm currently working on creating a Cookie from an endpoint. As my backend and frontend only interacts via RESTful endpoints, is there anyway I can create a cookie when the frontend calls my backend's endpoint?

`flask.make_response.set_cookie()` doesn't seem to work for me. Also, I can't use `app.route('/')` to set my cookie either.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with `Set-Cookie` [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) returning with a response.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'task': 'Hello world'}, 200, {'Set-Cookie': 'name=Nicholas'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: This answer works.  Note that for some reason, Chrome Inspector isn't showing such cookies, yet using Flask's `request.cookies` dict finds cookie just fine.

Comment: Hi @hamx0r, Could you share more idea about the request.cookie?

Answer (score 4):

Setting the header in the response tuple is one of the standard approaches. However, keep in mind that the **Set-Cookie header can be specified multiple times**, which means that a python Dictionary won't be the most effective way to set the cookies in the response.

According to the flask docs [the header object can also be initialized with a list of tuples](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.Headers), which might be more convenient in some cases.

Example:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
api = Api(app)

class CookieHeaders(Resource):
    def get(self):
        # Will only set one cookie "age = 23"
        return { 'message' : 'Made with dict'}, 200, { 'Set-Cookie':'name=john', 'Set-Cookie':'age=23' }

    def post(self):
        # Will set both cookies "name = john" and "age = 23"
        headers = [ ('Set-Cookie', 'name=john'), ('Set-Cookie', 'age=23') ]
        return { 'message' : ' Made with a list of tuples'}, 200, headers

api.add_resource(CookieHeaders, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The GET call will only set 1 cookie (due to the lack of multi-key support in python dictionaries), but the POST call will set both.

Answer (score 3):

Flask has a `@after_this_request` callback decorator. (see: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.after_this_request)

so you can set your cookies in it

```
from flask import after_this_request
from flask_restful import Resource

class FooResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        @after_this_request
        def set_is_bar_cookie(response):
            response.set_cookie('is_bar', 'no', max_age=64800, httponly=True)
            return response

        return {'data': 'foooo'}
```

or even

```
from flask import after_this_request, request
from flask_restful import Resource, abort

class FooResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        self._check_is_bar()
        return {'data': 'foooo'}

    def _check_is_bar(self)
        if request.cookies.get('is_bar') == 'yes':
            abort(403)

        @after_this_request
        def set_is_bar_cookie(response):
            response.set_cookie('is_bar', 'no', max_age=64800, httponly=True)
            return response
```